# How can I use if in if on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

If in view blade, it's like this :

```
<ul>
@if ($a)
    @if (!$b)
        <li>
            <p>...</p>
            ...
        </li>
    @endif
@endif
...
</ul>
```

I want change it to be vue component

I try like this :

```
<ul>
<li v-if="a" v-if="!b">
    <p>...</p>
    ...
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Seems it's wrong

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Why do you have two `v-if`s? `v-if="a && !b"` should be enough.

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, It's Great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options either you chain the condition as described by @Amresh Venupogal or you make a nested if just like you did in your bladeview. However it would require you to add an additional html element.

Option A

```
<ul> 
  <li v-if="a && !b"><p>...</p></li>
</ul>
```

Option B (obviously worse since you will create empty div's inside your unorderd list)

```
<ul> 
  <div v-if="a">
     <li v-if="!b"><p>...</p></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```